# Java epoch of System.nanoTime()?

Tags: java, time, epoch

I am trying to know what the epoch from `System.nanoTime()` is based on.
Apparently it is not based on 1970, because `(System.nanoTime()/1000000L)` (returns `31106704`)  no where near equals `System.currentTimeMillis()` (returns `1626111981278`).

Comment: It is completely arbitrary, as stated in the Javadoc. You should only ever be using nanoTime to measure time elapsed (between two invocations of the method), so the offset doesn't matter.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for the response! But I was wondering what factors determine the epoch. Could it be the time since the computer was booted or the JVM was started?

Comment: it could be, but it doesn't have to be. Don't rely on it being anything discernable: it doesn't matter if you are subtracting the difference between two nanoTimes.

Comment: You may try `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).minusNanos(System.nanoTime())` just out of curiosity. Don’t rely on reproducible results! They may be different next time you run the same program or next time you upgrade your Java and they are very likely to be different in practice (not only theoretically) when run on a different JVM or on a different computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the documentation of `nanoTime()` is fairly clear:

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). The same origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a Java virtual machine...

So:

- The epoch is **implementation-specific**, just what the authors of the method implementation thought would work;
- The epoch is **fixed throughout a JVM** instance;
- It may be that one or both of the values be negative, but the calculations are still correct in such cases.

So, should you care about the epoch? No. Absolutely not. Are you curious about *the* implementation? You can't, because there is no "the" implementation.